# Linq for mapping table

Tags: c#, linq

I dont know how to write linq for the given scenario. Any help please?

I have three tables

1. Employee ( have empid, name etc,)
2. Role (have roleid, rolename etc.,)
3. EmpRoleMapping(have roleid,empid)

I need a query to get the employeeName from employeetable and rolename from role table.

Any help please?

I am generating the mapping table in using entity framework like below, i am not getting the third table name, now to get the name of the table for writing the linq

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                .HasMany(role => role.Roles)
                .WithMany(emp => emp.employee)
                .Map(role => role.MapLeftKey("RoleId").MapRightKey("EmployeeId").ToTable("EmployeeRoleMapping"));
```

Comment: This is `linq` to what?

Comment: Think how you would write it in plain SQL. Then post that here, and we'll work from there.

Comment: You can install ReSharper. The program createsthe / converts code to a LINQ query. This way you can learn LINQ.

Comment: I assume you use EF right? Then what: model-first, database-first or poco? - Can you show us what you tried so far?

Comment: @Odrai: I don't think ReSharper can write you everything from nothing yet

Comment: @Odrai if he is used to ReSharper so he is not to learn anything..

Comment: Yes code first, linq to sql

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from emp in db.Employee
            join empRole in db.EmpRoleMapping
            on emp.empid equals empRole.empid
            join r in db.Role 
            on empRole.roleid equals r.roleid
            select new { employeeName = emp.name, rolename = r.rolename };
```

Comment: hi i am creating the rolemapping table runtime in my context, i am not getting the table. this is my code   modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
                .HasMany(role => role.Roles)
                .WithMany(emp => emp.employee)
                .Map(role => role.MapLeftKey("RoleId").MapRightKey("EmployeeId").ToTable("EmployeeRoleMapping")); how to get the table for writing my query please

Answer (score 0):

I guess this:

```
var result = employee.Select(e => e.name, e.Role.rolename);
```